# using one method's value in another

Tags: c#, web-services

I have a web service in which I am having 2 methods. First method am using to insert data to data base and this method am using in class library application. Second method am using in web application. Am calling class library application inside beb page using activex. I want to insert webpage values with classlibrary app values using first method.  Am not able to use session because new different sessions are  creating for class library and web page. Now am using static. But while using different users static will not work. Please Give me a solution for it.

```
namespace WSSeac
{
/// <summary>
/// Descrizione di riepilogo per Service1
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
// Per consentire la chiamata di questo servizio Web dallo script utilizzando       ASP.NET    AJAX, rimuovere il commento dalla riga seguente. 
// [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
//   [OperationContract]
// [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "/GetMyObject?id={id}", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]


public class Service1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    static string temp="";
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public void GetImages(byte[] front, byte[] rear, byte[] frontTif, byte[] frontUV,  string MICR,string mid)
    {
        //Here you can save the images inside the DATABASE
        //return "OK";
        SqlConnection _sqlConnection = new SqlConnection();
        SqlCommand _sqlCommand = new SqlCommand();

        _sqlConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["elogicConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        _sqlConnection.Open();

        _sqlCommand.Connection = _sqlConnection;
      // string aaa = HttpContext.Current.Session["aaaa"].ToString();
       string aaa = temp;

        string SQLString = "Insert into [elogic].[dbo].[seac](frontbw,backbw,frontgray,frontuv,micr,bank) values(@Content1,@Content2,@Content3,@Content4,@Content5,@Content6)";
      //  string SQLString = "Insert into [elogic].[dbo].[seac](frontbw,micr,bank) values(@Content1,@Content5,@Content6)";
        SqlParameter param1 = _sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Content1", SqlDbType.Image);
        param1.Value = front;
        SqlParameter param2 = _sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Content2", SqlDbType.Image);
        param2.Value = rear;
        SqlParameter param3 = _sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Content3", SqlDbType.Image);
        param3.Value = frontTif;
        SqlParameter param4 = _sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Content4", SqlDbType.Image);
        param4.Value = frontUV;
        SqlParameter param5 = _sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Content5", SqlDbType.Text);
        param5.Value = MICR;
        SqlParameter param6 = _sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@Content6", SqlDbType.Text);
        param6.Value = aaa;
        _sqlCommand.CommandText = SQLString;
        _sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        _sqlConnection.Close();


    }
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public void gettest(string bank)
    {
      temp = bank;
     //   Session["EmpName"] = bank;


    }

   [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]//session returns null
    public string GetName()
    {
        if (Session["EmpName"] == null)
        {
            return "";
        }
        else
        {
            return Session["EmpName"].ToString();
        }
    }
```